# TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate, Is there a way to access the TreeViewItem events like MouseDoubleClick and ItemSelected?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeviewitem

I made a TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate. Is there a way to access the TreeViewItem events like `MouseDoubleClick()` and `ItemSelected()`.

Here is my code:

```xml
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Artist}" ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is set an ItemContainerStyle and then use EventSetters

```xml
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.MouseDoubleClick"
                     Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
        <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Selected"
                     Handler="TreeViewItem_Selected" />

....
```

Comment: Where does that fit in relation to the HierarchicalDataTemplate?